# Fatal error during parsing and org.xml.sax.SAXParseException

Tags: javascript, spring, spring-mvc, reactjs, react-native

I am new to ReactJS while studying, I'm having this error and I'm having a hard time to replicate the error. *By the way I used Spring Framework for the backend.*

[image]

```
2017-04-05 13:12:16.556 ERROR 6000 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.thymeleaf.templateparser.ErrorHandler  : [THYMELEAF][http-nio-8080-exec-4] Fatal error during parsing

org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Open quote is expected for attribute "employees" associated with an  element type  "EmployeeTable".
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:203) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:177) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:441) [na:1.8.0_60]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:368) [na:1.8.0_60]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(XMLScanner.java:1437) [na:1.8.0_60]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.scanAttributeValue(XMLScanner.java:830) [na:1.8.0_60]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanAttribute(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1547) [na:1.8.0_60]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1319) [na:1.8.0_60]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2786) [na:1.8.0_60]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606) [na:1.8.0_60]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510) [na:1.8.0_60]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848) [na:1.8.0_60]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777) [na:1.8.0_60]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141) [na:1.8.0_60]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213) [na:1.8.0_60]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:649) [na:1.8.0_60]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:333) [na:1.8.0_60]
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.xmlsax.AbstractNonValidatingSAXTemplateParser.doParse(AbstractNonValidatingSAXTemplateParser.java:209) [thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.xmlsax.AbstractNonValidatingSAXTemplateParser.parseTemplateUsingPool(AbstractNonValidatingSAXTemplateParser.java:134) [thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.xmlsax.AbstractNonValidatingSAXTemplateParser.parseTemplate(AbstractNonValidatingSAXTemplateParser.java:116) [thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateRepository.getTemplate(TemplateRepository.java:278) [thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1104) [thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1060) [thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1011) [thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:335) [thymeleaf-spring4-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:190) [thymeleaf-spring4-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1282) [spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1037) [spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:980) [spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897) [spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) [spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861) [spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) [spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:105) [spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) [spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) [spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:474) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:783) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:798) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1434) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_60]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_60]

2017-04-05 13:12:16.556 ERROR 6000 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine             : [THYMELEAF][http-nio-8080-exec-4] Exception processing template "greeting": Exception parsing document: template="greeting", line 64 - column 42
2017-04-05 13:12:16.557 ERROR 6000 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Exception parsing document: template="greeting", line 64 - column 42] with root cause
```

And here is my HTML and javascript code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
        <title>React + Spring</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
       <div id="root"><div>
        <div class="container">
        <table class="table table-striped">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Age</th>
              <th>Years</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>{rows}</tbody>
        </table>
</div>
      

        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.3.0/react.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.3.0/react-dom.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/babel">
            var Employee = React.createClass({
                render: function() {
                  return (
                    <tr>
                      <td>{this.props.employee.name}</td>
                      <td>{this.props.employee.age}</td>
                      <td>{this.props.employee.years}</td>
                    </tr>);
                }
              });
              var EmployeeTable = React.createClass({
                render: function() {
                  var rows = [];
                  this.props.employees.forEach(function(employee) {
                    rows.push(<Employee employee={employee} />);
                  });
                  return (
                    <table>
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th>Name</th><th>Age</th><th>Years</th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>{rows}</tbody>
                    </table>);
                }
              });
              
              var EMPLOYEES = [
                {name: 'Joe Biden', age: 45, years: 5},
                {name: 'President Obama', age: 54, years: 8},
                {name: 'Crystal Mac', age: 34, years: 12},
                {name: 'James Henry', age: 33, years: 2}
              ];
              
              ReactDOM.render(
                <EmployeeTable employees={EMPLOYEES} />, document.getElementById('root')
              );
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answers are much appreciated! Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer and would like to share this. You  need to move your React code into a separate file. This is because Thymeleaf won’t like some of the characters. Move the code from the inside of the script tag into src/main/webapp/public/app.js

Use this sample code:

```
<script type="text/babel" src="/public/app.js"></script>
```